# How to write a code in GUI to receive multiple-input using for assign variable in calculation, Java, BlueJ

Tags: java

I'm taking class on basic Java programming class which my professor came up with a project assignment in Java. The topic is very wide open so I came up with "Expected grade calculation program" Here is my code for calculating.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ProAnalyziz
{
public ProAnalyziz()
{
    //declare variable
    double g,c,sum=0,mean,C=0,GPA,x=0,y,z,result=0;
    int amount;
   Scanner subjects = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner credits = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner gpa = new Scanner(System.in);

   //all grade will be input in fixed amount ex: 4,3.5,3,...,0 
   
   //create program parameter
   System.out.println("How many subject you have leaned this semester?");
   amount = subjects.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Please enter your expected GPA in this semester:");
   GPA = gpa.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Please enter your grade and credits of each subjects in order");
   System.out.println("If you don't know your grade, please type 0 ");
   System.out.println();
   
   //calculation part
   for(int order = 1; order<=amount; order++){
       //loop for storing input data
       System.out.printf("Subject No.%d : Your grade is: ",order);
       g = grade.nextDouble(); //input grade
       System.out.printf("Subject No.%d : Your credit is: ",order);
       c = credits.nextDouble(); //input credit
       if(g==0){
           //create coefficient of x
           x += c;
        }
       C += c; //total credits
       sum += g*c;
       System.out.println();
    }
    //mean for current known grade
       mean = sum/C;
    //create options
    if(mean>GPA){
        System.out.println("Your grade is " + mean);
        System.out.println("You already pass dude!!!");
    }
    else if(mean<=GPA){
        y = ((GPA*C)-sum)/x;
        //System.out.println(+y); (for checking error)
        if(y<=4){
            if(y<=1){//convert output answer to integer
                result = 1;
            }
            else if (1 < y&&y <= 1.5){
                result = 1.5;
            }
            else if (1.5 < y&&y <= 2){
                result = 2;
            }
            else if (2 < y&&y <= 2.5){
                result = 2.5;
            }
            else if (2.5 < y&&y <= 3){
                result = 3;
            }
            else if (3 < y&&y <= 3.5){
                result = 3.5;
            }
            else if (3.5 < y&&y <= 4){
                result = 4;
            }
            
            System.out.println("Your missing grade for each subject is " +result);
            System.out.println("End of program...");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("It's impossible for you to get out of this hell, sorry...");
            System.out.println("End of program...");
        }
}     
}
}
```

Actually, the code is perfect and the result is what I want but the problem is creating a GUI (which my prof said it is necessary). You can see that I need multiple input to calculate GPA depends on user and I have no idea how to write a text field code to receive multiple input for that. Any suggestion will be grateful.

Ps: So, I got a plan B. Which is using a combo box and let user click a fixed input like 4, 3.5, 3, ...., 0 and assign that to my variable in calculation part. Which will make my life a lot more easier but I still prefer it to be text input lol.

Ps2: My prof told me to use only BlueJ IDE so I can't use NetBeans or Eclipse or any other IDE.

---

Thank you for all of the suggestion but maybe I didn't make it clear enough (my bad lol)

I know that I can create a multiple text boxes to receive input from each one of them and assign them in to the variable. The thing is my variable that using in calculation method is depend on the user (you can see "for" loop for that)

ex: If I study 10 classes this semester which mean I need to input my grade and credit for each subject for 10 times (every time the user input it will be sum up with previous one).

That's mean I cannot make a specific text boxes (it could be 10, 12 or 20) or even I do (like creating 20 text boxes on the screen), it will be really weird. So, I try to find another solution instead of that.

So, I come up a new question. Can I make a GUI like a terminal when I run the console code? It will be the best solution for me if I can do that lol.

or, Can I make a text box to receive repeatable input? because all I need is to sum up the new input with the previous one.

---

#### Solved

Now, I can figure out the rest of the code I stuck. The result is

```
/**
* Write a description of class ProAnalyziz here.
*
* @author Bhuvanut Duangsasidhorn & 
* @version 1.00
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI_ProAnalyziz extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //Create the GUI elemts to use
    private JTextField tbxAmount;
    private JTextField tbxExpectedGPA;
    private JTextField tbxGrade;
    private JTextField tbxCredit;
    private JTextArea tbxOutput;
    private JButton btSubmit;
    private double totalCredits;
    private double coeficientX;
    private double sum;
    private double result;
    private double y;
    private double ExGPA;
    private int index;
    //Constructor of  the class
    public GUI_ProAnalyziz(){
       index = 0;
       sum = 0;
       totalCredits = 0;
       coeficientX = 0;
       ExGPA = 0;
       y = 0;
       totalCredits = 0;
       result = 0;
       coeficientX = 0;
       
       this.setTitle("ProAnalyziz Alpha v.1"); //Set title of the program
       //
       JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(); //Create a new panel to put in the textBox and labels
       panelLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2)); //Set the style of the layout
       panelLeft.add(new JLabel("Class you have taked this semester?")); //Attach a label in the panel
       tbxAmount = new JTextField(10);
       panelLeft.add(tbxAmount); //And inmediately attach the text box
       //the same as I did previously
       panelLeft.add(new JLabel("Expected GPA in this semester: "));
       tbxExpectedGPA = new JTextField(10);
       panelLeft.add(tbxExpectedGPA);
       Container panel = this.getContentPane(); //Create the container of the panels
       panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       panel.add(panelLeft);
       //
       JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
       panelCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
       //Create the right panel
       btSubmit = new JButton("Next");
       btSubmit.addActionListener(this); //Activate the action listener
       panelCenter.add(new JLabel("Grade : "));
       tbxGrade = new JTextField(10);
       tbxGrade.setEnabled(false);
       panelCenter.add(tbxGrade);
       panelCenter.add(new JLabel("Credit : "));
       tbxCredit = new JTextField(10);
       tbxCredit.setEnabled(false);
       panelCenter.add(tbxCredit);       
       panel.add(panelCenter);
       JPanel panelRight = new JPanel(); //Create a new panel to put in the textBox and labels
       panelRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); //Set the style of the layout
       panelRight.add(btSubmit);
       panel.add(panelRight);
       JPanel panelRightRight = new JPanel(); //Create a new panel to put in the textBox and labels
       panelRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); //Set the style of the layout
       tbxOutput = new JTextArea(20, 50);
       tbxOutput.setEnabled(false);
       panelRightRight.add(tbxOutput);
       panel.add(panelRightRight);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       
            if(e.getSource() == btSubmit)
        {
            if(tbxAmount.isEnabled() && tbxExpectedGPA.isEnabled()){
                tbxGrade.setEnabled(true);
                tbxAmount.setEnabled(false);
                tbxCredit.setEnabled(true);
                tbxExpectedGPA.setEnabled(false);
                //btSubmit.setText("Attach");
                return;
            }
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(tbxAmount.getText());
            double credit = Double.parseDouble(tbxCredit.getText());
            double grade = Double.parseDouble(tbxGrade.getText());
            double y = Double.parseDouble(tbxExpectedGPA.getText());
            
           
            //__________________________________Output message___________________________________________
            String output = "Subject No. " + Integer.toString(index + 1) + ": Your grade is : " + String.valueOf(grade) + "\r\n";
            output += "Subject No. " + Integer.toString(index + 1) + ": Your grade is : " + String.valueOf(credit) + "\r\n\r\n";
            tbxOutput.append(output);
            //__________________________________Increase items____________________________________________
            
            index++;
            
            //__________________________________Calcuation _______________________________________________
            
            if(grade == 0){
                coeficientX += credit;
            }
           
            
            totalCredits += credit;
            
            sum += grade*credit;
            
                
            result = ((y*totalCredits)-sum)/coeficientX;
            
            //_________________________________Go in this if when the program finish______________________
            
            if(index == Integer.parseInt(tbxAmount.getText())){
                tbxGrade.setEnabled(false);
                tbxCredit.setEnabled(false);
                btSubmit.setEnabled(false);
                //____________________________________Finsih calculate__________________________________
                String out = "Your missing grade for each subject is : "+ String.valueOf(result);
                
                tbxOutput.append(out);
            }
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI_ProAnalyziz frame = new GUI_ProAnalyziz();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I have no idea how to write a text field code to receive multiple input for that_" Just make multiple text boxes...

Comment: Don't add IDE tags, your question is not actually related to the IDE. You can write the same code in any IDE.

Comment: You should avoid combining GUI and console code. Make it all GUI, get your user input via the GUI (JTextFields, JComboBoxes,...), and display the result using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

On first glance you should really be using a single Scanner for your inputs. Secondly to get an input to a you can call an update method on that UI element by either passing in a reference to it or having it accessible. I'd post code but answering this from mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! but I still really don't get it lol. I just started my class last month and I really know a few in Java programming (my English skill make it even harder lol).